# WiFi disconnecting

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I am facing annoying problem. My NB Asus ux303u with Intel AC7265 WiFi adapter wont work correctly with my home WiFi. Wifi keeps dropping in about five minute intervals for a few seconds. When I run ping to 8.8.8.8 I have about 15% drop rate. NB is running Win 10 64Bit. Other devices are working fine (another laptop, iPhone...)

Here is what I have tried:

- driver updated to latest version available
- switched off powering off device in device manager
- maximum performance in power management
- changed modes on router and in advanced settings to b/g/n modes only
- scanned channels - looks good, very low interference. I am the only one on channel 2. Also router is in the same room as notebook
- channel wide from auto to 20MHz only
- transmit power to maximum

No change at all. 
Any tips what to try more?

Thank you very much

Comment: install the latest intel wifi driver: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26527/ and don't use the drivers from ASUS

Comment: this is really strange. have you tried to boot a linux live DVD? Does it also happen here? if yes, the wifi card may has some issues

Comment: Channel 2 is a poor choice because it overlaps two other 2.4 GHz channel groups. Only channels 1, 6, and 11 do not overlap. Your Wi-Fi will need to yield to devices using both channels 1 and 6. Also, Wi-Fi is not the only source of interference in 2.4 GHz. Bluetooth, wireless phones, microwave ovens, etc. all use 2.4 GHz, and can interfere with 2.4 GHz wi-Fi.

Comment: Try this : cmd -> netsh int ip set global taskoffload=disabled && netsh int tcp set HEURISTICS DISABLED && netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled I have the experience that the offload function with Windows 10 leads to strange behaviors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you all for your tips.
I have tryed Knopix live distribution which works without any problem, so HW problem eliminated.

performing 
netsh int ip set global taskoffload=disabled && netsh int tcp set HEURISTICS DISABLED && netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled
helped a little bit, but still droping in slower rate.

Router was configured to auto channel so I changed that to channel 6 and voila. No drops. There is still 1% ping packed loss, but it works fine.

Thank you all for your tips